# Использование сторонних элементов на HTML+CSS+JS в Angular 6

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование, angular2, frontend, angular5

Всем привет.
Подскажите пожалуйста как правильно вставить сторонний элемент на HTML+CSS+JS
в компонент Angular.

К примеру, я хочу использовать данную таблицу на бутсрапе: https://datatables.net/extensions/select/examples/initialisation/simple.html

Со стилями и разметкой вроде все ясно, но как правильно подключить зависимые JS файлы, и проинициализировать ее?

Я подключил зависимые JS файлы в angular.json

Создал следующий компонент:

```
    export class MyComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
       @ViewChild("foo", {read: ElementRef}) 
                                          foo:ElementRef

            constructor() { }

            ngOnInit():void { }

            ngAfterViewInit(): void {
        this.foo.nativeElement.DataTable({select: true});
        }

   }
```

Соответсвенно пометил таблицу как  "#foo"

Но чет работать не хочет.

Comment: А что говорит, как не хочет работать, какой результат?

Comment: Подключить удалось, но пошли ошибки в подключаемых файлах js, думаю из-за отсутствия заголовочных файлах на TS,  на обычной html странице все работает. Впрочем, проще самому написать